# npm install angular/cli error

Tags: node.js, npm, angular-cli

node -v **8** and npm -v **5**. Trying to install **angular/cli** globally from yesterday. Facing new error everytime.

> Vipins-Air:~ vipingupta$ sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
>       npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
>       npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
>       npm ERR! network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 74.122.238.10:8080
>       npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
>       npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
>       npm ERR! network 
>       npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
>       npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
>       npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>       npm ERR!     /Users/vipingupta/C:Devnodejsnpm-cache/_logs/2017-06-07T06_37_13_337Z-debug.log

Comment: try this npm config delete proxy

Comment: Try updating your `npm` to the latest version.

Comment: this can be caused either by a firewall or a proxy.

Comment: @David R try this  `npm config set proxy null`

Comment: Are you working in corporate(company proxy) ? If yes , then I have the solution .

Answer (score 8):

If you are getting the below message:

> npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

you need to set proxy

```
$ npm config set proxy http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX
```

and

```
$ npm config set https-proxy http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX
```

give your proxy ip address and port number(4digits)

if you dont want to use proxy remove it using below command

```
$ npm config rm proxy   
$ npm config rm https-proxy
```

To check the current proxy

```
$ npm config get proxy
```

Answer (score 5):

Remove the proxies by running the following commands.

```
npm config rm proxy

npm config rm https-proxy
```

It should work now.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
npm config set proxy http://USERNAME:PASS@IP_Address:PORT_NO/
```

- don't delete `http://`
- `USERNAME` is your name in your physique machine
- `PASS` is your password in your physical machine

After that try to install your packages for example: `npm install -g @angular/cli`

Comment: I have tried using the npm config set proxy. But I was still facing the issue. Then I opened the command line in the project folder and use set http_proxy=_proxy_name_. This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean cache 
"npm cache clean"

uninstall angular-cli
"npm uninstall -g angular-cli"

install again
"npm install -g angular-cli"

If this doesn't work, use Force flag (-f).

And also make sure your network connection is descent.

Comment: facing issue same again:- I run sudo npm cache clean --force,   sudo npm uninstall -g @angular/cli, sudo npm install -g @angular/cli

Answer (score 0):

1.) try "npm config set proxy http://USERNAME:PASs@IP_Address:PORT_NO/"

2.) Make sure that the proxy is set by running the below command
 npm config get proxy

3.) After that when we try to install it was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Reset the firewall settings

in windows 10
go to Setting -> Update & security -> Windows Security -> FireWall & Network protection

and click on Restore firewalls to default

good luck