# error showing for angular cli installation

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I am trying to install angular cli but it showing error .
the error is

```
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxy.comviva.com proxy.comviva.com:8080
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\malaya.choudhury\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-12-03T07_09_20_267Z-debug.log
```

Please give me the solution.

Comment: Did you check the possible error causes described in the message?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559648/is-there-a-way-to-make-npm-install-the-command-to-work-behind-proxy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm install angular/cli error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44405323/npm-install-angular-cli-error)

Answer (score 0):

Working answer from an already asked question:

In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings. First, run npm config list and check whether you are behind a proxy. If so, try running

npm config delete proxy
npm config delete http-proxy
npm config delete https-proxy

Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54512973/15291281