# Error during Angular-cli installation using npm

Tags: angular, npm, command-line-interface, failed-installation

When I try to install Angular-cli using npm I get err with code ETIMEDOUT

I tried to remove proxy (proxy & HTTP-proxy), tried to run cmd in admin mode, changed the path to nodejs destination

```
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.22.35:443
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\123\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-02-04T09_5I_06_689Z-debug.log
```

It doesn't matter what I tried but have same error everytime. Need help guys

Comment: That's probably network issue. I too had this error on poor connections.

Comment: it's might be a network issue. try 'npm cache verify' and  connect high bandwidth internet connection then do npm install

Comment: yeah i guess so, i am connected with high bandwidth internet connection but maybe something is blocking the data transfer. Is any way to force it ?

Comment: C:\Users\123\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-02-04T09_54_06_689Z-debug.log open this file and check for access denied or any network issue which will be listed here.

Comment: Obviously this is not a network issue. Its an angular issue. Looks like angular is written very poorly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
First, run npm config list and check whether you are behind a proxy. If so, try running

```
npm config delete proxy
npm config delete http-proxy
npm config delete https-proxy
```

Comment: Unfortunately i'm not behind the proxy ( i checked that in npm config list every proxy = null ) What could be wrong in my network settings?

Comment: Disabling your router's firewall may solve the issue if that's the problem.

Comment: I am using my android's hotspot to use the internet. It worked for me too.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your internet connection. This is a internet issue at your place.

Comment: I have internet connection all the time.

Comment: Please try and ping 104.16.22.35 from your system

Comment: Request timed out

Comment: you are unable to access the cloudfare content hosting service where the module is hosted. Please try and install any other module.

Comment: i tried with ngx-bootstrap and same here. I have to wait a lot to even get an error from npm. 
Its something wrong with my internet. What is interesting - any website or download is working just fine

Comment: try this ip 104.16.22.35 in browser? Are you getting the error page of direct access is not allowed?